# During free list, there is one segment error

Tags: c++, c, linked-list, free

Two functions, one is  to create a link list, the other is to free the link list.
If the Create function return a double pointer to the head node, use this node to free the link list, will encounter a segment error. But if changing the Create function to return a pointer to head node, then free the list, this will be OK.

Anyone who can explain this for me? Here is the code which have the segment errors:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct ListNode{
    int m_nValue;
    ListNode* m_pNext;
}ListNode;

ListNode** CreateList(int data[], int length){
   if(length<=0 || data == NULL)
       return NULL;
   ListNode *pHead = (ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
   ListNode *pNode = pHead;
   pNode->m_pNext = NULL;
   pNode->m_nValue = data[0];
   int i=1;
   for(; i<length; i++){
       ListNode *temp = (ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
       temp->m_nValue = data[i];
       temp->m_pNext = NULL;
       pNode->m_pNext = temp;
       pNode = temp;
   }
   return &pHead;
}

void FreeList(ListNode **pHead){
    ListNode *pNode;
    while(pHead!=NULL && *pHead!=NULL){
        pNode = *pHead;
        *pHead = pNode->m_pNext; // here will encounter an error;
        free(pNode);
    }
    pHead = NULL;
}

int main(){
    int data[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    ListNode **pHead = CreateList(data, sizeof(data)/sizeof(int));
    FreeList(pHead);
}
```

But if I change the CreateList's return type to ListNode* CreateList(...), this will work well.

```
ListNode* CreateList(int data[], int length){
     if(length<=0 || data == NULL)
          return NULL;
   ListNode *pHead = (ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
   ListNode *pNode = pHead;
   pNode->m_pNext = NULL;
   pNode->m_nValue = data[0];
   int i=1;
   for(; i<length; i++){
       ListNode *temp = (ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
       temp->m_nValue = data[i];
       temp->m_pNext = NULL;
       pNode->m_pNext = temp;
       pNode = temp;
   }
   return pHead;
}
int main(){
    int data[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    ListNode *pHead = CreateList(data, sizeof(data)/sizeof(int));
    FreeList(&pHead);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ListNode** CreateList(int data[], int length)` approach you are returning pointer to a local variable, which clearly goes invalid when the function returns.

That is, you declare a pointer variable `ListNode* pHead` in `CreateList` function and you return address of the variable `pHead`. The pointer variable `pHead` is stored in stack and when the CreateList function returns the stack is unwinded memory used to stored `pHead` is freed eventhough the memory pointed to by `pHead` is still availalbe on heap.